# Python 3 aiohttp | Optimize server response time

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp import ClientSession

# this would go in a different file but keep it simple for now
class Generate:

    # Get a person object from my website
    async def get_person(self):
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get('http://surveycodebot.com/person/generate') as response:
                resp = await response.json()
                # this prints the person
                print(resp)
                return resp

    # loops `get_person` to get more than 1 person
    async def get_people(self):
        # array for gathering all responses
        for _ in range(0,10):
            resp = await self.get_person()
        return resp

# class to handle '/'   
class HomePage(web.View):
    async def get(self):
        # initiate the Generate class and call get_people 
        await Generate().get_people()
        return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', HomePage)
    web.run_app(app)
```

Code works and everything is fine. I was wondering why the `HomePage` takes a while to load. I think I should be using yield on line 28, but it barfs when I do that. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like if I change the url to another server it works faster. Looks like the code is find an need to optimize the server code from where the Get request is made. i.e change `http://surveycodebot.com/person/generate` to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`         Again now if there is a way to optimize let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize by sharing the session between several client requests via the aiohttp `on_startup` signal.

Something like the following will do:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp import ClientSession


class Generate:

    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    # Get a person object from my website
    async def get_person(self):
        async with self.session.get('http://surveycodebot.com/person/generate') as response:
            resp = await response.json()
            # this prints the person
            print(resp)
            return resp

    # loops `get_person` to get more than 1 person
    async def get_people(self):
        # array for gathering all responses
        for _ in range(0,10):
            resp = await self.get_person()
        return resp

# class to handle '/'   
class HomePage(web.View):
    async def get(self):
        # initiate the Generate class and call get_people 
        await app['generate'].get_people()
        return web.Response(text="Hello, world")


async def on_startup(app):
    session = ClientSession()
    app['generate'] = Generate(session)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', HomePage)
    app.on_startup.append(on_startup)
    web.run_app(app)
```